# No binary built in eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have a c++ project in eclipse cdt. source files are put in folder 'srt-lsh'. However, I can not build the project successfully. No Binary is shown after I hit the 'build all' button. When I try to run it, 'launch failed, no binary found' dialog pops up.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I resolved this... by including g++ as the compiler...

Comment: I'm new to C/C++ (and compilers, I mainly program in R, which is like Python). Care to guide me on how to include a compiler?